# Dense subsets of Projective Limit from Compact Topological spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, limits-colimits

Suppose $(X_i, \varphi_{i,j})$ is a projective system, with $X_i's$ being compact Hausdorff spaces. Take $X=\varprojlim X_i$. Is it true that $X_i$ is "dense" in $X$, in that:
$$X=\overline{\bigcup\limits_i X_i}$$
I'm fairly certain there's a similar result concerning inductive limits and their connecting maps, which is why I believe that it should hold. But it is not obvious that is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: What does $\bigcup_i X_i$ even mean? The sets $X_i$ do not include into the projective limit $\lim_{\leftarrow} X_i$.

Comment: It's possible that that is not the correct approach. I'm basing it off of that if $X_i$ is an inductive system with inductive limit $X$, then the closure of $\bigcup\limits_i\Delta_i(X_i)$ is equal to $X$, where $\Delta_i: X_i \to X$ is the embedding map from the inductive limit construction. I hope that that makes sense.

Comment: Yes -- there are inclusion maps from the objects in an inductive system to the inductive limit. Dually, there are projection maps *from* a projective limit to the objects in the projective system!

Comment: Right, yes. So my question then is does the density argument work similarly for projective limits? Obviously, it won't be the case that for the projection $\pi_i: X\to X_i$, that $\pi_i(X_i)$ is "dense" in $X$ (for lots of reasons). But is there a "dual" type argument to say that $X_i$ is dense in $X$? For some notion of dense? I hope that makes sense.